# internal server error in ejs page

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and express please bear with me if I cant catch up fast, my problem is I am using LINE login api modue and in my callback url object I set to render it to profile.ejs whenever authorization is success, however when I try to output the object in profile ejs   `<p><%= tt %></p>` it renders 500 internal server error

This is my server.js

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const line_login = require("line-login");


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

const login = new line_login({
    channel_id: 48,
    channel_secret: "6b7",
    callback_url: app.get("/profile", function(req, res) {res.render("pages/profile")}), // render callback page
    scope: "openid profile",
    prompt: "consent",
    bot_prompt: "normal"
});

// here you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// here you set that you're using `ejs` template engine, and the
// default extension is `ejs`
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`server is listeninssssg to ${process.env.PORT || 5000}...`);
});

// Specify the path you want to start authorization.
app.use("/", login.auth());

// Specify the path you want to wait for the callback from LINE authorization endpoint.
app.get("/callbackurl", login.callback((req, res, next, token_response) => {
    // Success callback
    console.log(token_response);
//     res.send(token_response);
     res.render('pages/profile', {
       tt:token_response
     });
    // //res.render('pages/profile');
},(req, res, next, error) => {
    // Failure callback
    res.status(400).json(error);
}));
```

How can I output the token_response in my profile.ejs page? `<p><%= tt %></p>` Thank you

Comment: Have you any details on that 500 error>

Comment: no it just shows internal server error, and in console there's no details too

Comment: Most likely your token_response isn't getting a value. If you set a breakpoint on the line `console.log(token_response);`, what's its value? What line is causing the 500 error?

Comment: ah what do you mean setting a breakpoint?